# Access print server through firewall?

Tags: networking, firewall, domain, print-server

At my workplace, we have two fiber networks setup, one for the business network and the other for process control (industrial manufacturing). On the business network, there is a standard print server that all computers on the business network can access.

On the process network side, we would like to be able to print on the business network printers, however, I am stumped as to how I would do this.

I should mention, that the business and process network each operate on their own domains and are separated by a firewall.

Comment: Take a look at IPP.  It uses a single port and should be easy to set up through a firewall.  Or, but another printer...

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look into it yet, but would it require that I setup a print server on the process network side?

Comment: Yes, but the printer could have the print server built in.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you can open port 9100 on the business network firewall so the process network can print to the printers in the business network.

What no one else has said so far though was to make sure you build you ACLs on the business router to only allow port 9100 traffic from the business network and no other IP addresses and make sure your NAT rules are configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a network printer, it should already listen on port 9100 which is ment for "raw" printing, you can just open this port on the firewall and add the printer to your print server like any other network printer.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the IP address of the firewall in your process network to the allowed list on your business firewall.  This will allow access to your business network from your process network going externally.

Additionally, depending on the actual physical location of the two firewalls and the availability of open ports on your devices you could pair the two devices to allow traffic to pass between the two firewalls without having to go over the network.  Without knowing specifics of what hardware you are running for your firewalls I cannot try to locate a guide on how to implement these possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to setup network to access Samsung C480FW printer behind NAT of "Pix-Link Access Point Wi-Fi Repeater".

The outside devices accesses printer by the external PixLink Address. The inside devices can also use external address which simplifies configuration if the devices moves between networks.

I checked what is in use with wireshark and forwarded ports 8018 161 6498 38438 27663 18864.
Additionally I added printer as a DMZ host.

Disclaimer: the external address is still in other private network and nothing was forwarded to public address.

long story:
https://www.fantatec.com/2023/08/printer-behind-nat.html